# How to disable youtube third party's cookies when embedding a video on site dynamically?

Tags: javascript, cookies, youtube

I need to implement a way to comply with the new EU law about third party cookies. I've managed to restrict when needed the most of them but I can't restrict youtube's cookies from embedded videos.

It seems that the videos run even without those cookies, so the functionality is preserved.

These are the cookies I'm reffering to (all of them are from .youtube.com domain):

```
VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE (path /)
PREF (path /)
use_hitbox (path /)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change domain from youtube.com to youtube-nocookie.com.